# ng2-signalr Freeze web site while going back and forward

Tags: signalr

I couldn't find the answer why when I am  going back and forward in pages that implement the resolver, suddenly signlar stop working, and all my Angular 6 freeze. (you couldn't click on any link) the web site look ok, but nothing is working..

I am using
"ng2-signalr": "^6.1.0",
Angular 6.0.3

I implemented the ng2-signalr, 
The Resolver did not work at start, than I changed it to use ISignalRConnection
I can do up to 5 time back and forward in the 6'th time the application Just FREEZE,

```
export class SignalrConnectionService implements 
Resolve<ISignalRConnection> {
@Injectable()
export class SignalrConnectionService implements Resolve<ISignalRConnection> 
{
    constructor(private _signalR: SignalR) { }
    resolve() {
        console.log('ConnectionResolver. Resolving...');
        //this._signalR.createConnection();
        try {
            return this._signalR.connect();
        }
        catch (err) {
            console.log("Error in _signalR.connect: " + err.message);
        }
        //return this._signalR.createConnection();
    }
}
```

Inside the Routing I did:

```
path: 'my_path',
component: MyComponent,
canActivate: [AuthGuard],
resolve: { connection: SignalrConnectionService }
```

If I remove the resolve line, the signalR is canceled and everything work (with no freeze and no signalR), but I need it..

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

So I found the solution.
It seems that you don't need to use the resolver, instead in the constructor, do this:

> constructor(private _signalR: SignalR) {
>
> this._connection = _signalR.createConnection();
>
> }

And only then in the **ngInit** you can put code like this:

> this._connection.start().then((c) => {
>
> //what ever
>
> ```
>     });
> ```
>
> });

That seems to solve the problem :)